Failed to load local spark pipeline model
I want to load local spark pipeline model(fit). But when I try loading the pipeline model from local path, the error occurs.
Here is my full code. The code is copied from PipelineExapmle from Github)  , I just change the name and a little code. But it is supposed to run without problems.
// $example on$
import org.apache.spark.ml.{Pipeline, PipelineModel}
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{HashingTF, Tokenizer}
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
// $example off$
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("PipelineExample")
      .master("local[*]") // 使用本地模式，*表示使用所有可用的CPU核心
      .getOrCreate()

    // $example on$
    // Prepare training documents from a list of (id, text, label) tuples.
    val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (0L, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
      (1L, "b d", 0.0),
      (2L, "spark f g h", 1.0),
      (3L, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)
    )).toDF("id", "text", "label")

    // Configure an ML pipeline, which consists of three stages: tokenizer, hashingTF, and lr.
    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer()
      .setInputCol("text")
      .setOutputCol("words")
    val hashingTF = new HashingTF()
      .setNumFeatures(1000)
      .setInputCol(tokenizer.getOutputCol)
      .setOutputCol("features")
    val lr = new LogisticRegression()
      .setMaxIter(10)
      .setRegParam(0.001)
    val pipeline = new Pipeline()
      .setStages(Array(tokenizer, hashingTF, lr))

    // Fit the pipeline to training documents.
    val model = pipeline.fit(training)

    // Now we can optionally save the fitted pipeline to disk
    model.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")

    // We can also save this unfit pipeline to disk
    pipeline.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/unfit-lr-model")

    // And load it back in during production
    val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")

    // Prepare test documents, which are unlabeled (id, text) tuples.
    val test = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (4L, "spark i j k"),
      (5L, "l m n"),
      (6L, "spark hadoop spark"),
      (7L, "apache hadoop")
    )).toDF("id", "text")

    // Make predictions on test documents.
    model.transform(test)
      .select("id", "text", "probability", "prediction")
      .collect()
      .foreach { case Row(id: Long, text: String, prob: Vector, prediction: Double) =>
        println(s"($id, $text) --> prob=$prob, prediction=$prediction")
      }
    // $example off$
    // Make predictions on test documents.
    
    sameModel.transform(test)
      .select("id", "text", "probability", "prediction")
      .collect()
      .foreach { case Row(id: Long, text: String, prob: Vector, prediction: Double) =>
        println(s"($id, $text) --> prob=$prob, prediction=$prediction")
      }
    spark.stop()
  }
}

But after I click to run, the terminal shows:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/io/nativeio/NativeIO$POSIX$Stat;
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.stat(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.getStat(NativeIO.java:608)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfoByNativeIO(RawLocalFileSystem.java:934)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:816)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:2199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:2179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:300)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$take$1(RDD.scala:1428)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$first$1(RDD.scala:1463)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1463)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$.loadMetadata(ReadWrite.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$.$anonfun$load$3(Pipeline.scala:269)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$SharedReadWrite$.load(Pipeline.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.$anonfun$load$7(Pipeline.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withLoadInstanceEvent(events.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.MLEvents.withLoadInstanceEvent$(events.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation.withLoadInstanceEvent(Instrumentation.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.$anonfun$load$6(Pipeline.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.$anonfun$instrumented$1(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.Instrumentation$.instrumented(Instrumentation.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$PipelineModelReader.load(Pipeline.scala:349)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable.load(ReadWrite.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLReadable.load$(ReadWrite.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel$.load(Pipeline.scala:337)
    at com.yu.controller.Test$.main(Test.scala:53)
    at com.yu.controller.Test.main(Test.scala)

It means the error occur when running  val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")
If I add annotation to the sentence  val sameModel = PipelineModel.load("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model") and code blocks using variable sameModel, the program runs well.
My demand is loading spark pipeline model from local path. But why loading local model will cause error?
How can I solve it?

My environment:  spark-version:3.2.0    java-version: jdk8  scala-version:2.12.13

Thanks for your help. However, there is no answer for that question
